# VS2017 Intellisense not finding definition for rand()

Tags: c++, visual-studio, intellisense, visual-studio-2017

In my Visual Studio 2017 RC Professional installation, Intellisense cannot seem to find some methods like `rand`, but also `atof` or the struct `time_t`. However, my code *is* compiling and running correctly.

I have tried running `devenv /resetSettings` and even a complete reinstallation of VS 2017 to no avail.

I suspect it may be something to do with some environment variable not being set correctly, however I do not know which variables might be responsible. In my project properties under VC++ directories, my `Include Directories` is set to `$(VC_IncludePath);$(WindowsSDK_IncludePath);`, and the contents of these variables evaluates to:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.10.24911\include
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.10.24911\atlmfc\include
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Auxiliary\VS\UnitTest\include
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\shared
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\winrt`

Comment: Does disabling VS2017 lightweight solution load help?

Comment: @RustyX This is already disabled

Comment: I test it in my VS2017 RC Pro version, it works normally, but in my project property->Include Directories, it was different from yours like: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.10.24728\include. Yours is 14.10.24911. My VS version is 15.0.26014.0 in windows 10. I will install the latest update package, test it again.